# $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto f(x,y,z):= (x^2+y^2+z^2+8)^2-36(x^2+y^2)$. Let $M:=f^{-1}(0)$. Find the $T_cM$ and provide a basis for it.

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Let $c=(0,3,1)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto f(x,y,z):= (x^2+y^2+z^2+8)^2-36(x^2+y^2)$. Let $M:=f^{-1}(0)$. Find the $T_cM$ and provide a basis for it.

### My attempt:

I think we need to find the differential and then the columns of the differential matrix evaluated at $c$ will be the basis for it? Not sure how to approach this one

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the tangent space at the point c, your best friend is the gradient $\nabla f$, since the tangent space at a point c will be the two-dimensional vector space (unless you'd like to look at the more geometric affine version) consisting of all vectors $v$ such that $(v, \nabla f (c)) = 0$. To find a basis, you could just guess a single non-zero vector $v$ that lies in that space, and then find the second basis vector by taking the cross product $v \times \nabla f(c)$.

Comment: You made a small mistake, $f(c) = (9+1+8)^2 - 36 (3^2) =0$

Comment: you're absolutely right, I'll delete that passage of shame ;)

Comment: Schultz from wolfram, the gradient of this function is $(4x(x^2+y^2+z^2-10),4y(x^2+y^2+z^2-10,4z(x^2+y^2+z^2+8))$ now if I evaluate this at c..$=(0, 0,72)$.. Now what?

Comment: Well, that is much easier than what you would usually hope for. The normal vector points in z-direction, so the orthogonal complement (a.k.a. your tangent space) is the xy-plane. A basis for this would be provided by (1,0,0) and (0,1,0).